# How to get chrome extension name and status by using extension Id in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension Id which I am getting from Registry (`\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\{exID}`). I want to get the Extension name by using that Id. How to get that? I checked "Preference" file also but didn't get the relevant info in that.

I am doing this in WPF and C# so I am trying to avoid Javascript here.

Comment: Your question's content was useful (for others); don't edit it out, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently looking at the `Secure Preferences` file in the profile folder, and it contains all the data you need.

Google moved the extension data there and protected it with cryptographic hashes on Windows to fight malware, but the data you need is there unencrypted.

It's a JSON-formatted file that contains, among other things, copies of manifests of all installed extensions. Having `{exID}` you will find the name at the following path of the `Secure Preferences` file:

```
extensions.settings.{exID}.manifest.name
```

You will find other properties as well under the `manifest` key.

How to find the file and how to parse JSON is outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I checked the Secure Preferences file and found the info which I am looking for. But I want to know how I to extract info from that. Should I use SQLite and pass that file as a datasource or any other way you can suggest me to achieve it. My purpose is to extract name and state from that file based on exID.

Comment: Find a library that parses JSON format. Can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name, description, and more about any installed extension checking its `manifest.json` file, which is located inside:

```
<chrome-user-data>/Extensions/<extension-id>/<version>/manifest.json
```

To get the full path just replace the text wrapped between < and > with the following:

- `<chrome-user-data>` with one of the paths listed [HERE](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory), depending on your operating system.
- `<extension-id>` with the ID of the extension you want to check.
- `<version>` is not important, it's just the forst folder inside the extension-id folder.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I already checked mainfest.json file and found nothing relevant in that. In that file "description" is mentioned like "__MSG_web2pdfExtnDescription__" and "name" is like "__MSG_web2pdfExtnName__".